# How to aggregate in mgo bson for a field type map[string]uint32?

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregate, bson, mgo

I am trying to get aggregated values from a mongo collection using bson and Golang where the field used in Golang is of type `map[string]uint32`.

This is the struct am using and the field is `Csat`.

```
type Conversations struct {
     ID   bson.ObjectId     `bson:"_id"`
     Csat map[string]uint32 `bson:"csat"`

}
```

The output using bson should be in key value pairs, these are some examples I tried but did not work,

1.

```
bson.M{

    "csat["1"]": bson.M{
        "$sum": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$score", 1}}, 1, 0}},
    },
    "csat["2"]": bson.M{
        "$sum": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$score", 2}}, 1, 0}},
    }
```

2.

```
bson.M{
        "csat": bson.M{
            "1": bson.M{
                "$sum": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$score", 1}}, 1, 0}},
            },
            "2": bson.M{
                "$sum": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$score", 2}}, 1, 0}},
            },
        }
    }
```

I expect it to store it like `{"csat": {"1": 3}, {"2": 2}, ...}` where 3 and 2 could be values of the keys.

If anyone has done something like this before, can you please help me out?

Thanks.